# Javascript Show full image only on click otherwise fit screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to display single image on a web page so that :

If the image is smaller than screen of the user. Full Image is shown

Otherwise if the image is larger than user's screen then it should fit screen and **once image is clicked only then full size is shown .**

Here is my html

```
<html>
<body>
<div class="img">
<img src="imagepathhere.jpg" />
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the css that I have tried but I guess it is not possible by just only using css:

```
    <style>
    html,body{
    min-width:100%;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    }

    .img {
    padding:0px;
    width:auto;
    text-align:center;
    margin:auto;
    }
    .img img {
    max-width:100%;
    }
</style>
```

What would be best way to do it?

Ahmar.

Answer (score 1):

## Toggle `max-width:100%` on click

The easiest way to do this is to add this property to a class instead of applying it to the tag name

```css
.img .shrinkToFit {
    max-width:100%;
}
```

And then use JQuery to toggle it on click

```js
$(".img").on("click", function() {
    $(this).find("img").toggleClass("shrinkToFit");
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/TrevinAvery/anryho0o/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution  that confines the image as you described, but to it's parent div, rather than the entire screen (to make it easier to use as an example). It uses the css `:not()` selector which may not have full browser support.

http://codepen.io/sean9999/pen/LlCJa/

```js
"use strict";

$('#toggleimage a').on('click',function(){
  $('.img img').prop('src', $(this).data('imgSrc') );
});

$('.img img').on('click',function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('fullsize');
});
```

```css
    html,body{
      min-width:100%;
      margin:0px;
      padding:0px;
      background-color: silver;
   }

   .img {
      padding:0px;
      width: 450px;
      height: 450px;
      background-color: white;
      text-align:center;
      margin:auto;
      border: 1px dotted gray;
   }
   .img img:not(.fullsize) {
      max-width:100%;
      max-height: 100%;
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="toggleimage">
  <li><a href="#" data-img-src="http://nerdhow.files.wordpress.com/2008/02/mushroombgbig.png">load big image</li>
  <li><a href="#" data-img-src="http://api.jquery.com/jquery-wp-content/themes/jquery/images/logo-jquery.png">load small image</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="img">
  <img src="http://api.jquery.com/jquery-wp-content/themes/jquery/images/logo-jquery.png" />
</div>
```